# What is the difference between closed under intersections of finitely many subsets and closed under countable intersections?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is given in definition, that $\sigma$ algebra is a type of algebra of sets. So if algebra of sets is defined as being closed under intersections with finitely many subsets, does that mean that being closed under countable intersections implies being closed under intersections with finitely many subsets? Countable set is a set which is bijective to a subset of natural numbers? If so, does finitely many mean that you can also have a bijective function with natural number set? And then, why is that important in probability?

Comment: There are two good answers which give examples of families of subsets that are closed under finite intersection but not countable intersection. I will add that the fact that this is possible is the reason for the "$\sigma$" in the name "$\sigma$-algebra." A family of subsets closed under complement and *finite* intersection is just called an "algebra". The $\sigma$ is there to insist that it's closed not only under finite but also countable intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being closed under arbitrary finite intersections does not imply being closed under countable intersections. For example, take the family of co-finite subsets of the natural numbers, that is, the family $F$ of sets whose complement is finite. So, e.g., $\{3,4,5,6,\ldots\}$, which omits the finite set {$0,1,2$}, is in $F$, but the set of even numbers is not (because it’s complement is infinite).

Now, any intersection of finitely many sets from $F$ is in $F$ because the complement of that intersection is the union of the complements, i.e. a finite union of finite sets, which is finite.

But if you look at the countably many sets $A_n = N - \{n\}$ for $n = 0, 1,2,3,\ldots$, each one is in $F$, but their intersection is empty, and the empty set is not in $F$. So $F$ is not closed under countable intersections.

Comment: You shouldn't switch in and out of MathJax in the course of writing an expression in mathematical notation. Just stay in MathJax, thus:
$\{3,4,5,6,\ldots\}$ rather than {$3,4,5,6\ldots$} and $A_n = N-\{n\}$ rather than $A_n$ = N-{$n$}. The font sizes fail to match and you don't get proper spacing, and your minus sign looks like a hyphen, when you switch back and forth.

Comment: @Ned oK, I am really sorry, I wanted to ask the question other way round, because it seems that $\sigma$ algebra has more restrictive definition, if some collection of subsets can be defined as $\sigma$ algebra, does that implies that it is closed under intersection with finitely many subsets?

Comment: @Ned Why it's important in probability theory that $\sigma$ algebra not like general algebra of sets is closed under countable intersections?
So the biggest idea of $\sigma algebra$ is an empty set?

Comment: @user Yes, sigma algebra is more restrictive, any family closed under countable intersections is automatically closed under finite intersections by taking a finite intersection and making it infinite by repeating sets in the intersection. I'm not an expert (to put it mildly) on abstract probability, but one point is that you want to be able to do continuous probability (e.g. the normal distribution), which is very much like real analysis and measure theory, where countable unions and intersections occur everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{-1} n , \frac 1 n \right) = \{0\}.
$$
This is an intersection of countably many open sets, but it is not an intersection of finitely many open sets. An intersection of finitely many open sets would be open, but this set is not open. “Open” in this context would mean containing an open interval about each of its points.

Comment: I think the question is about "closed" in a different sense. I don't know much about $\sigma$-algebras but here what I think it means is that if $x,y\in\Sigma$ then $x \cap y\in\Sigma$.

Comment: @roundsquare Yes, you're right. It is not about intervals.

Comment: @roundsquare This is exactly how he is using it. The open (in the topological sense) subsets of the reals are an example of a collection of sets that is closed (*not* in the topological sense) under finite intersections but not under countable intersections.

Comment: @roundsquare : Closure of $\sigma$-algebras under finite intersections does mean that if $x,y\in\Sigma$ then $a\cap y\in\Sigma.$ How is that a different sense from what appears in my answer above? My example shows that closure of a particular class of sets (in this case open sets) under finite intersection does not mean that class is closed under countable intersection.